# Check signal strength mobile timely

Tags: android, service

I need to check my mobile signal strength every 10 secs to send data to server.
I have some data in sqlite. After these 10 seconds gone I send the data.
I have a service with a listener to get the changes on signal. The verification works fine when service start but I can't get signal data throughout the lifecycle. My application has some activities and this service starts in the very beginning.

How can I timely verify the signal in the service and and my data?

```
public MyService extends IntentService{
   public MyService(){
   ...
   telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) App.getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

   telephonyManager.listen(
                new PhoneStateListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength){
                        int signalStrengthPercentage = 0;
                        int gsmSignalStrength = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
                        if(signalStrength != null && gsmSignalStrength != 99){
                            signalStrengthPercentage = (int) ((float) gsmSignalStrength / 31 * 100);
                        }
                        signalIsStrength = signalStrengthPercentage >= 50;
                        Log.e("ERROR", "Percentage: "+signalStrengthPercentage);
                    }
                }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop this and you will get the result.

```
 long delay = 10000;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            //your code to verify the signal strength

            }
        }, delay);
```